# How to write a grammar with a low-precedence unary postfix operator?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, parsers

Like [this person on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.compilers/c/DW4_ESTikec/m/Z0JHsGoQoYAJ), I'm trying to understand how to write a grammar involving Wolfram Language's low-precedence unary `&` operator.

The operator [works like this](https://wolfram.com/xid/0giru6-gz5):

```
g[#, #^2] & /@ {x, y, z}
```

The `g[#, #^2] &` part builds an anonymous function `# -> g[#, #^2]`, and then `/@` maps it over the list `{x, y, z}`.

However, `&` has [much lower precedence](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) than `/@`. How come the expression above is parsed as:

```
(g[#, #^2] &) /@ {x, y, z}
```

My question is, how do I write a grammar with `&`, this low-precedence *postfix* operator?

A similar question was asked here: [Binary operators with higher precedence than unary operators](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18835/binary-operators-with-higher-precedence-than-unary-operators), but 1) it's about a unary *prefix* operator and 2) the answer doesn't explain *why* it "evaluates just fine".

Also, I had no issues parsing a part of Modelica's expression which involves unary *prefix* `+` and `-` operators that have *lower* precedence than the binary `*` and `/`, for example (see Table 3.1 [here](https://specification.modelica.org/master/operators-and-expressions.html)). So it seems that the issue lies in `&` being a *postfix* operator.

---

I tried the usual (?) approach suggested in [Crafting interpreters](https://www.craftinginterpreters.com/parsing-expressions.html#ambiguity-and-the-parsing-game):

1. Write one rule for each precedence level, starting with low-precedence rules and going down to high-precedence ones.
2. Implement the rules so that "each rule only matches expressions at its precedence level or higher".

Given a language like `a & /@ b` (I don't care about the `g[#, #^2]` and `{x, y, z}` parts at the moment), I wrote this grammar:

```
start: function

// Low precedence first
function: map
 | function "&"

// High precedence next
map: symbol
 | map "/@" symbol

// This is basically a terminal,
// so it has the highest precedence.
symbol: /[a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]*/
```

However, as mentioned [in the same Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.compilers/c/DW4_ESTikec/m/oObDJ29az5EJ), the postfix `&` operator in the `function` rule tries to "become" the entire expression:

> When this operator occurs in an expression, it means "everything which comes before me in the expression is my argument".
>
> The problem with this is that it leaves no room for the construct to be
> *embedded* in another one. Since the operator says "everything is mine!" it
> means, by the same token (pun intended) that "I am not a subexpression; I am
> the top-level constituent!". And since that is the case, because it is a postfix operator, it means that the expression ends right there.

Indeed, when I try to parse `a & /@ b` with LALR(1) using [Lark](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark), I get an "unexpected character" error:

```
lark.exceptions.UnexpectedCharacters: No terminal matches '/' in the current parser context, at line 1 col 3

a&/@b
  ^
Expected one of: 
        * AMPERSAND
```

So it tries to parse `function`, but it *must* be followed by `&` and nothing else, so `/@` following `&` is a syntax error. Quoting the Google Groups post again, "because it is a postfix operator, it means that the expression ends right there", so `a&` can't be an *argument* of the binary `/@` operator.

---

Are there any standard ways of transforming the grammar to make `a& /@ b` be equivalent to `(a&) /@ b` without hacks in the parser?

In general, how to write a LALR(1) grammar which allows *subexpressions* that involve low-precedence unary *postfix* operators?